# Converting Pantone to RGB

Tags: color-conversion, rgb, pantone

I need to convert my client's logo from Pantone to RGB.

The first is Pantone 297. If I convert it to RGB, is it  R130, G198, B226?

How about the blacks? I am not sure what these percentages mean.

Pantone Black 70% 
Pantone Black 60%
Pantone Black 40
Pantone Black

Please assist! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There are conversion charts online. Use google to find them.  A percentage of Pantone Black refers to a half-tone tint of black in CMYK printing. On white paper, these tints will look grey, and the lower the percentage of black, the lighter the grey.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert a Pantone color wich is preferred for print and you only use it on digital devices, you can't get a 100% matching result, because every monitor/screen displays a color differently. So you can try to get as close as possible.

Here is an official answer from pantone to the Problem that says:

> "Adobe Photoshop, which supports both the CMYK and RGB color spaces
>   and PANTONE Colors, can default to the closest PANTONE Color to a
>   given set of CMYK or RGB colors."

https://www.pantone.com/customer-service/help/?t=CMYK/RGB-to-Spot-PANTONE-Color

Answer (score 1):

No, no...

First of all, there is not only one 297 color. There are a ton of them. You probably mean 297C.

There is not only one way to convert a Pantone color to RGB. I can summarize that there are a right way and many wrong ways.

You can not convert a color if you do not define the color space and the color profile of the output data...

You need to set up the correct values on your professional application. CorelDraw, Illustrator, Photoshop for example.

---

For practical reasons you can simply go to Pantone's official site https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/297-C

These conversions, (although is wrongly not stated), according to my tests use the Swop2 specification, which is for North America.

---

> Pantone Black 70%

Again this is wrong... There are more than two dozen "blacks". You need to first define what black.

For example Black3C.

From there you do not print a flat black, you just use a percentage of the ink using some screening on the final print. Black3C 50%.

Any ink at 0% will be white, or the paper's color, meaning there is no ink.